# ld: can't link with a main executable file for architecture i386 error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I want to add unit test target to my Xcode project which consist of lots of sub-projects. I'm adding test target to my main project. After I add it, I can't build it from test target (I can successfully build app target, just can't build test target).

Some settings are **not** default;

```
Build Active Architecture Only -> Yes (On my main target)
Test Target iOS Deployment Target -> 10.3
```

I'm getting below error

> ld: can't link with a main executable file '/Users/emreonder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAppWorkspace-gdwblguzoliffpbypfnfrxayzvpe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp' for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
>   Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm using Xcode 11.

Comment: Please post the complete linker error message.

Comment: I edited the error.

Comment: Yeah there should be more detail about the root cause available.

Comment: This is the only error I get.

Comment: So you get nothing more expanding the build log line (lined icon in top-right of build log line)?

Comment: @EmreÖnder Did you find any solution?

Comment: No. I couldn't figure out to add unit test target to the project.